# Bash script to read file and echo different lines to output files

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a log.txt file with various lines of strings and information.

I want to write a script to read the log.txt file line by line and any line that contains the word debug I want to put that line into a new file called debug.txt and all other lines should go to info.txt.

What is the best way to go about doing this? I tried to do a while loop but couldn't figure it out. Thanks

Comment: You _can_ process text files line by line in bash, but it's really not recommended. And it's slow, since the bash `read` command reads its input data byte by byte. For further info, please see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/88378), and the associated links. I _was_ going to post an answer containing a short script using grep, and also mentioning that you can easily do it using awk, but Archemar has beaten me to it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are zillion way to do it, first two I came with are awk and grep (in that order)

## awk

```
awk '/debug/ { print > "debug.txt" ; next ;} { print } ' logfile > info.txt
```

where

- `/debug`/ select line with word debug
- `{ print > "debug.txt" ;`  print to debug.txt
- `next ;}` read next line in logfile
- `{ print }` if no debug, print to stdout
- `> info.txt` redirect stdout to info.txt

a more formal command

```
awk '/debug/ { print > "debug.txt" ; } 
  $0 !~ /debug/ { print > "info.txt " ; } ' logfile
```

where

- `$0 !~ /debug/` means, if debug does not appear on the line.

## grep

```
 grep    debug logfile > debug.txt
 grep -v debug logfile > info.txt
```

where

- `grep debug` select line with debug
- `grep -v debug` select line without debug
- logfile is read twice

please note also that previous content of debug.txt and info.txt will be deleted by using `>` to keep it, use `>>` in shell or in awk.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `bash` script to do the job :

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ debug ]]; then
        echo "$line" >>debug.txt
    else
        echo "$line" >>info.txt
    fi
done <log.txt
```